# Custom cursor goes back to default when hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am working on a website where I am implementing custom cursors. These cursors change according to the background, however, the cursor goes back to default when near/on-top of the earth image. Here is my html code:

```
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="season winter" data-background="#2b1055">Winter</div>
            <div class="season summer" data-background="#5988e2">Summer</div>
            <div class="season spring" data-background="#7cdea1">Spring</div>
            <div class="season autumn" data-background="#cf8a8a">Autumn</div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                <img id="earth" src="img/earth.png" alt="scroll">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
}

.season {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  &[data-background="yellow"] { color: #333; };
}

.winter {
  cursor: url('img/winter-cursor.png'), auto;
}

.summer {
  cursor: url('img/summer-cursor.png'), auto;
}

.spring {
  cursor: url('img/spring-cursor.png'), auto;
}

.autumn {
  cursor: url('img/autumn-cursor.png'), auto;
}

.wrapper {
  top: 120%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
}

#earth {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

JavaScript (for the rotating of earth and changing of background upon scroll):

```
// Rotating earth 
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollRotate();
};

function scrollRotate() {
  let image = document.getElementById("earth");
  image.style.transform = "rotate(" + window.pageYOffset / 24 + "deg)";
}

// Background change 
window.sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('.season')];
window.lastScrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

document.body.style.background = window.sections[0].getAttribute('data-background');

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll() {
  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  const section = window.sections
    .map(section => {
      const el = section;
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {el, rect};
    })
    .find(section => section.rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight * 0.5));

  document.body.style.transition = 'background 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)';
  document.body.style.background = section.el.getAttribute('data-background');

}
```

In order to fix this issue, I tried rearranging the positing of elements in the html file by moving the earth image down, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried changing the cursor to none for #earth in css file but that just made the cursor disappear altogether :(

Any responses are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So what do you want the cursor to look like when it is over that image?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  
  var getCurrentClassName =//add some code for getting class name based on scroll;
  scrollRotate(getCurrentClassName);//"winter"
  
};

function scrollRotate(seasonName) {
  let image = document.getElementById("earth");
  image.classList.replace(seasonName);
  image.style.transform = "rotate(" + window.pageYOffset / 24 + "deg)";
}
```